# How Do I Copy a table from one Access DB to another Access DB

Tags: ms-access, vbscript, ado

I am trying to automate a process to create a secondary database from a primary. Both DB's (MS Access) contain one table; the table in the secondary DB is a subset of the table in the primary.

Is there a simple way to copy a recordset frone one DB to another? I am using VBScript and ADO.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have SQL server available?

Comment: Is this a one time job? If you could, create a link table from base table into seconday table. The code then will become much simpler.

Comment: Couldn't you just copy the file?

Answer (score 1):

Try the CopyObject method:

```
DoCmd.CopyObject "DestinationDatabaseName", "NewName", acTable, "SourceTable"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run Insert queries referencing external Access database files files (MDB, ACCDB, etc).  For example:

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO ServiceRecordInvoices " & _
    "( sriID, sriServiceRecordID, sriInvoiceDate, sriInvoiceNumber, " & _
                                "sriDescription, sriInvoiceAmount ) " & _
    " IN '" & strDatabasePathandNameTo & "' " & _
    "SELECT srpID, srpServiceRecordID, srpInvoiceDate, srpInvoiceNumber, " & _
                                "srpParts, srpPartsAmount " & _
    "FROM ServiceRecordParts IN '" & strDatabasePathandNameFrom & "';"
```

Note the two string variables `strDatabasePathandNameTo`  and `strDatabasePathandNameFrom`.   The above dynamic SQL code will work fine in either DAO or ADO.

If the two tables are identical then you could use the following (untested):

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO ServiceRecordInvoices.* " & _
    " IN '" & strDatabasePathandNameTo & "' " & _
    "SELECT * " & _
    "FROM ServiceRecordParts IN '" & strDatabasePathandNameFrom & "';"
```