# How do I copy data from a table in an Access DB on a server to another Access DB

Tags: sql, vbscript, ms-access-2010, ado

I know that there is a similar question already posed. Since the answers are more than 6 years old, I started a new thread.

I have a Access DB and a copy of that DB. The plan is to write data to the copy and then automatically the new data to the original. So basically both DBs are the same.

I found and answer here: [How Do I Copy a table from one Access DB to another Access DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209681/how-do-i-copy-a-table-from-one-access-db-to-another-access-db). Now I want to adapt this to my purpose but I fail.

I have attached the SQL string

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO [maintblKeyFinancials].* " & _
    "IN '" & destination_DB & "' " & _
    "SELECT * FROM [maintblKeyFinancials] " & _
    " WHERE [Company_ID] = " & identifier & _
    " AND [Reference_year] = " & Chr$(34) & Year & Chr$(34) & ";"
```

Yes, [Reference_year] is a string. I also attached the Output

```
INSERT INTO [maintblKeyFinancials].* IN 'C:\destination.accdb'  
SELECT * FROM [maintblKeyFinancials] IN 'C:\source.accdb'  
WHERE [Company_ID] = 899 AND [Reference_year] = "2015";
```

When I execute the string, I get "syntax error in query. incomplete query clause". And I don't know what to correct. Hope you can help me. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO [maintblKeyFinancials].*
```

Remove the `.*` at the end, this gives the syntax error. It's either

```
INSERT INTO [maintblKeyFinancials] (column1, column2)
SELECT column1, column2 FROM ...
```

or if the columns are completely identical

```
INSERT INTO [maintblKeyFinancials]
SELECT * FROM ...
```

Answer (score -1):

write [YourServer].[yourSchema].[YourTable]

SELECT * FROM [YourServer].[YourSchema].[maintblKeyFinancials]

Comment: Sarver? Youer? Secema? And all this on MS Access?

Comment: Well, typos were fixed, but proposed solution will work on SQL server, not in MS Access.